# Using chronosys package in standalone class

Tags: errors, standalone, crop, bounding-box, chronosys

I want to include a timeline in a beamer presentation. To that end I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{first-period}{HTML}{b3e2cd}
\definecolor{second-period}{HTML}{fdcdac}
\definecolor{third-period}{HTML}{cbd5e8}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont
\definechronoevent{MySmallerEvent}[textstyle=\footnotesize,datestyle=\footnotesize]

\startchronology[startyear=1980,
  stopyear=2020,
  dates=false,
  color=third-period,
  height=7ex]

\chronoperiode[color=first-period, dates=false]{1980}{2000}{}
\chronoperiode[color=second-period, dates=false]{2000}{2010}{}
\chronoperiode[color=third-period, dates=false]{2010}{2020}{}

\chronoMySmallerEvent[textwidth=5ex]{1990}{First event}
\chronoMySmallerEvent[textwidth=8ex]{2005}{Second event}
\chronoMySmallerEvent[textwidth=5ex]{2015}{Third event}

\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: Timeline]
Then, in the appropriate frame I put this:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, keepaspectratio, trim = 45mm 210mm 45mm 40mm, clip]{timeline.pdf}
```

The problem with this approach is that I have to manually adjust the trim values, which is time consuming.

I thought I could avoid the need of trimming the figure by creating the timeline using `standalone` instead of `article`, but this is what I got:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.29 \stopchronology
                    
? 
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.29 \stopchronology
                    
? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.29 \stopchronology
                    
? 
! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 
                          
l.29 \stopchronology
                    
? 
! Extra \endgroup.
\color@endgroup ->\endgraf \endgroup 
                                     
l.31 \end{document}
                   
? 
! Too many }'s.
\endsa@boxit ...dvarwidth \color@endgroup \egroup 
                                                  
l.31 \end{document}
                   
?
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: I've removed the `beamer` tag since your example doesn't use it and added a couple which seem more relevant. Of course change them if you disagree.

Answer (score 2):

First, it seems chronology fits the timeline to `\textwidth`, so you need to put it inside a minipage.  Second, it doesn't create a bounding box, so standalone crops off part of the right side.  So I used an `\hrule` to change the width without changing the height (`\rule` would add an extra blank line).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{first-period}{HTML}{b3e2cd}
\definecolor{second-period}{HTML}{fdcdac}
\definecolor{third-period}{HTML}{cbd5e8}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t][1in][s]{4in}% set height to 1 in, width to 4 in
\hrule width\textwidth height0pt%bounding box?
\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont
\definechronoevent{MySmallerEvent}[textstyle=\footnotesize,datestyle=\footnotesize]
%
\startchronology[startyear=1980,
  stopyear=2020,
  dates=false,
  color=third-period,
  height=7ex]
%
\chronoperiode[color=first-period, dates=false]{1980}{2000}{}
\chronoperiode[color=second-period, dates=false]{2000}{2010}{}
\chronoperiode[color=third-period, dates=false]{2010}{2020}{}
%
\chronoMySmallerEvent[textwidth=5ex]{1990}{First event}
\chronoMySmallerEvent[textwidth=8ex]{2005}{Second event}
\chronoMySmallerEvent[textwidth=5ex]{2015}{Third event}
%
\stopchronology
\vss% shrink bottom
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution removes the right and left margins (which is not bad at all because this gets half of the job done) but I still have to adjust the horizontal and vertical trim values.

Comment: The only thing left to trim is the space at the bottom, and that is from chronology itself.

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay any attention to your trim values.  Were you trimming off part of the timeline itself?

Comment: The edited answer works fine for the example provided. But if you add more `chronoevent`'s with different `markdepth` values, then the top and bottom margins are incorrectly trimmed off. I tried to adjust the minipage's height, to no avail.

Comment: My advice is to leave the extra space on the bottom in.  If you need to,, add some negative \vspace after.